# Data Grid Control In C# Using MySQL Database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio

I'm developing a basic app in Windows OS using VS C# Express and MySQL as my database. Now, the purpose of my app is to just list all the profiles in a data grid in a form. Now my question is what data grid control in C# .net that I can use to list my profiles in my mysql database? And how to populate that grid control with the data from the database in the code?

I already have a working database. I can also query the database in the C# code.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[DataGridView](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=msdn%20datagridview&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx&ei=MwVKT6SkMY71sgbskcmUBQ&usg=AFQjCNEiQdb3mXteMFK-2zaZjr-XBJ3GLw&sig2=wMcsSo3UHznWn0jDW8yI6A&cad=rja) is the Data Grid you want

There are several ways to fill it with data. 
The simplest way would be just to bind the data to DataGridView. [See this article on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx).

Binding is really easy. Lets say you fill your MySql results to a some enumerable of class Cat (this is a scenario of using some ORM). Binding is easy:

```
class Cat
{
   [DisplayName("Cats Name")]
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Likes {get; set;}
}

...
public void BindCatsToGrid(List<Cat> cats)
{
    bindingDataSource = new BindingDataSource();
    bindingDataSource.DataSource = cats;
    grid.DataSource = bindingDataSource;
}
```

But you can control rows and columns manually. Or, even, switch to so called 'virtual mode' for displaying the huge sets of data.

There is [a good article about using DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7za025w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a DataGridView to display you're data

```
string sql = "SELECT ProfilCode, ProfilName FROM Profils";
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   using(MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
   {
      adapter.Fill(myTable);
   }
}

dataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

Good luck